# Sequential addition to list based on predecessor presence in another list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two lists: `myList` containing elements `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and a final list `cacheList` initially having `[1]`. I am looking for an algorithm or method to dynamically add elements to `cacheList` based on the order in `myList`. The constraint is that each element should be added to `cacheList` only if its predecessor is already present in `cacheList`. How can I achieve this sequential addition while maintaining the order from `myList`?

```
final List<int> originalList = [1, 2, 3, 4];
final List<int> cacheList = [1];
```

expect: `cacheList = [1, 2, 3, 4];`

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  To get your example inputs and expected output, you could just copy the original list.  Or if `cacheList` might start with an element other than the first element of the original, you could find the last element of `cacheList` in the original list and copy all elements after it.